# Custom taxanomy and custom post type - pagination leads to 404

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have a custom post type that is introduced with this setting:

```
$args = array(
            'label'                 => __( 'Location', 'genesis' ),
            'description'           => __( 'Locations', 'genesis' ),
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'genesis-cpt-archives-settings'),
            'taxonomies'            => array( 'location', 'type_of_location', 'post_tag' ),
            'hierarchical'          => true,
            'public'                => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_in_menu'          => true,
            'menu_position'         => 5,
            'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
            'can_export'            => true,
            'has_archive'           => 'location',
            'exclude_from_search'   => false,
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'capability_type'       => 'page',
            'rewrite'       => array('slug' => 'location/%locations%','with_front' => false),
        );
        register_post_type( 'location', $args );
```

Additionally I have added three taxonomy's to this custom post type with this command:

```
register_taxonomy( 'kind_of_location', 'location', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'location/kind', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
        ),
    ) );
```

Then I added this rewrite logic to replace the %locations% in my CPT URL setting:

```
add_filter('post_link', 'category_permalink_locations', 1, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'category_permalink_locations', 1, 3);

function category_permalink_locations($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%locations%') === FALSE) return $permalink;
        // Get post
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if (!$post) return $permalink;

        // Get taxonomy terms
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'kind_of_location');
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0]))
            $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        else $taxonomy_slug = 'sonstiges';

    return str_replace('%locations%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

This works fine unless I am on my taxanomy archive page and click on the link to see the previous posts - then I get an 404.

Something must be wrong in my setup ;-) Does anybody knows why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve it by myself - I had to register the taxonomy **BEFORE** the post type...